# Get error and resubscribe

Tags: java, android, rx-java

Is it possible to resubscribe an Observable and get the error?

The [`Observable<T> retry()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#retry()) method resubscribes the observable but it consumes the error.

```
final PublishSubject<Integer> observable = PublishSubject.create();
observable
    .flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Integer>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<Integer> call(final Integer integer) {
            if (integer % 2 == 0) {
                return Observable.just(integer);
            } else {
                return Observable.error(new Exception("int: " + integer));
            }
        }
    })
    .retry()
    .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {

                   @Override
                   public void call(final Integer integer) {
                       Timber.i("integer: %d", integer);
                   }
               },
               new Action1<Throwable>() {

                   @Override
                   public void call(final Throwable throwable) {
                       Timber.e(throwable, "throwable");
                   }
               },
               new Action0() {

                   @Override
                   public void call() {
                       Timber.w("onCompleted");
                   }
               });

Observable
    .range(0, 10)
    .delay(2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {

                   @Override
                   public void call(final Integer integer) {
                       observable.onNext(integer);
                   }
               },
               new Action1<Throwable>() {

                   @Override
                   public void call(final Throwable throwable) {
                       observable.onError(throwable);
                   }
               },
               new Action0() {

                   @Override
                   public void call() {
                       observable.onCompleted();
                   }
               });
```

The `onError` part of `observable` is never called because `.retry()` consumes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`retryWhen()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#retryWhen(rx.functions.Func1)). This allows you to pass a `Func1` which provides you with the `Throwable`, that means you can place your `onError` logic there instead.

This is a good [article](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/).